# SQL & BITS Errors on prereq for SCCM 2012

Tags: sql, sccm, bits

Hey anyone that can help,

I've been stumped by this problem for a while now and I've no idea what to do.

I've installed SQL 2008 to run with SCCM '12. I've set Log On As a domain account with administrator privileges. I've set SQL browser to run as automatic. I've cursed at it and shaken my fist. I've restarted countless times, I've tried running as a local service. I've already opened the appropriate ports.

That's also just for SQL. I've installed and (I think) enabled BITS on the same machine with the same results in a sense. It's telling me that it's not installed nor enabled.

Here are a few pictures to show my settings within services and the errors included.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The prerequirements to install SCCM 2012 screen. It's throwing back errors on the check saying that my sQL installation isn't running a domain account (it is) and that I'm using the wrong collation (i'm not).

[image]

Event viewer:

[image]

Comment: Clearly, what are you trying to do and what is not working ? Please show details from Event Log errors.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the prerequirements to install SCCM 2012. It's throwing back errors on the check saying that my sQL installation isn't running a domain account (it is) and that I'm using the wrong collation (i'm not). There are no error logs to report as it's just a check.

Comment: Your Windows Error Log Event **have details**, please post it

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/aHfdF

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ilxn3NJ.jpg also event viewer. The error you see is from me trying to start it up something different sql related within services. I can post any other tabs you're interested in.

Comment: Are you using a default instance of SQL or a named instance?  It's possible you have assigned a domain account to one but are configuring the other in the wizard?

Comment: I'm using a named instance (SCCM)